# Make Opensea send royalty payouts to a contract

Tags: solidity, ether, nft

I am trying to send royalties to a contract instead of an account. First I am only testing the feasibility of contract receiving funds from opensea through their royalty mechanism.

```
contract Sink {

  mapping (address => uint256) private _shares;
  constructor(address holder, uint256 share) {
    _shares[holder] = share;
  }

  receive () external payable {}
}
```

Just a simple example acting as a `sink`, after I deployed this and made opensea on rinkeby send payouts of resales to this address.

I can find the payouts `pending` but the balance of the contract remains the same despite that the amount of payouts are bigger than 60 USD.

[image: Payouts by Opensea]

Comment: did you ever sort this out?